# How to access json nested objects in node.js

Tags: json, xml, node.js

I have used xml2js parser to parse the xml file in node.js. It is parsing the xml successfully. But now i want to parse the json or to identify the particular data in json.

My node.js code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString; 
var xml = 'C:\\temp\\Masters.xml'; 
var fileData = fs.readFileSync(xml,'utf8'); 
parseString(fileData, function (err, result) { 
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
var json = JSON.stringify(result); 

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json); 
for (var key in jsonObj) { 
console.dir(key + ": " + jsonObj[key].Customer_Name); 
} 
});
```

In console output:

```
'Masters: undefined'
```

Json data:

```
'{"Masters":
  {
    "Customer":

  [
  {"Customer_Name":["Kim"],
  "Customer_Code":["c86"],
  "Date":["23-11-15"],
  "Address":["Narhe"],
  "City":["Pune"],
  "State":["Maharashtra"],
  "TIN":["3365670"],
  "PAN_Number":["AAAAA1111a"],
  "Mobile_Number":["8999000090"],
  "Email_ID":["amitshirke@gmail.com"],
  "Contact_Person":["Anish"],
  "Opening_Balance":["0"] },

  {"Customer_Name":["Ankit"],
  "Customer_Code":["c87"],
  "Date":["12-04-15"],
  "Address":["Narhe"],
  "City":["Pune"],
  "State":["Maharashtra"],
  "TIN":["336567"],
  "PAN_Number":["AAAAA1111p"],
  "Mobile_Number":["8900000000"],
  "Email_ID":["amitshirke1@gmail.com"],
  "Contact_Person":["Anuj"],
  "Opening_Balance":["0"] }
  ]
 }
}'
```

In above data, Masters is root element(Object), Customer is another nested object and there two customers. Then how can I access the customer names or how to use the for loop to access the same?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ohh sorry. but how can I access the customer names or any other data in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `Customer` array as follows -

```
var customerArray = Masters.Customer,
    length = customerArray.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // You can access the customers array from here - 
    console.log(customerArray[i].Customer_Name[0]); // [0] hardcoded because as you can see all the variables are in array at 0th position 
   // similarly you can access other data 
   console.log(customerArray[i].City[0]);
}
```

Comment: for (var i=0; i<jsonObj["Masters"]['Customer'].length; i++){
   
 var name= jsonObj["Masters"]['Customer'][i];
   console.log(name['Customer_Name']);
}